# Json Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, json

Пытаюсь запарсить json, но постоянно возникает сообщение об ошибке.

От сервера приходит вот такой json (это часть довольно большого json):

```
"[{\"id_list\": [19], \"meas_lat\": 55.788652215575866, \"meas_lon\": 49.00268204440898}, {\"id_list\": [1], \"meas_lat\": 64.0, \"meas_lon\": 24.66}, {\"id_list\": [18], \"meas_lat\": 75.0, \"meas_lon\": 80.0}, {\"id_list\": [13], \"meas_lat\": 22.0, \"meas_lon\": 34.0}]"
```

Пытаюсь его запарсить с помощью Gson (пока хотя бы разложить на элементы коллекции ArrayList()):

```
Gson g = new Gson();
ArrayList<String> list = g.fromJson(lims,new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType());
```

При этом, проверку на валидность json проходит (проверял на https://jsonlint.com/), но постоянно выдается сообщение об ошибке:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2 path $

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашел:

Нужно было немного подправить сам json в части:

```
json=json.replaceAll("\\\\","");         //удаляем backslash
json=json.substring(1,json.length()-1);  //удаляем кавычки в начале и в конце
```

И за тем запарсить например вот так:

```
 ArrayList<SearchElem> list = g.fromJson(json,new TypeToken<ArrayList<SearchElem>>() {}.getType());
```

Где класс SearchElem:

```
public class SearchElem {

    private Double meas_lat;
    private Double meas_lon;
    private ArrayList<Integer> id_list;
   
    public SearchElem(){}
}
```

Тогда парсится корректно.
Надеюсь кому пригодится